# How to do a graceful shutdown in Windows 11 without unnecessary document recovery?

Tags: windows

I have an open Excel workbook, which I saved. If I close it, then it won't ask for anything.

I do shutdown or restart. When I open the file again, it asks about document recovery, as if the app was terminated unsuccessfully.

I'd like Windows 11 restart to send close window message to all main windows and alert me if an app doesn't want to close.

For most apps, Windows 11 restart is fine. Maybe it's just MS Windows not compatible with MS Office?

---

I'll try to clarify.

An app can have either a graceful or a forced termination. For example:

1. Chrome. You close all the windows, the process terminates, and it ends gracefully.
   You kill the process, then it's forced, and next run it will ask if to restore your tabs.
2. Excel. You close the window. If there are no changes, then it ends gracefully. Otherwise, it will ask you to save. If you kill the process, then next run it will ask about doc recovery.

When Windows shuts down, it tries to end the current process. With Chrome, there's no problem. Next run it won't ask me about recovery.

Excel, even if nothing needs saving, it will ask about recovery as if it was terminated ungracefully.

For another app (maybe Visual Studio?) that requires saving, it would report that it prevents restart and should it ignore it.

Anyway, this is the situation. One resultion that I see is an app that I can run before shutting down, which will close all windows. I tried a couple in the past, but they didn't close all apps gracefully. Maybe I should just write my own script the sends WM_CLOSE to all main windows?

Comment: If you shut down a machine with a document open, the OS has no idea what your intent is. Meaning it doesn’t know if you cleanly shutdown on your own or crashed.

Comment: You can try writing your own script but so far as I can see things are working properly when shut down without saving and closing

Answer (score 3):

Windows 11 (10, 8, 7 and back) are working correctly.

Windows is not responsible for saving your documents and cannot be during a shutdown process.

So the best thing to do is close all Apps prior to shutdown / restart. This works fine and prevents the document recovery requirement.

This is not unique at all to Excel. Same thing for Word, all Other Office, Adobe Editing (Pro), Notepad and so on.

Overall closing Apps is good maintenance and practice and the correct way to do things.

The document recovery in Office and some other tools is meant for abrupt shutdowns (power loss, system damage, hardware issue and so on). It is not designed to allow forgetting to close apps.

**Follow up note**:  For certainty, Windows 11 (and 10) will start up Apps closed on shutdown. Go to Settings Apps and scroll down to Startup to set Apps to automatically startup on sign in.  That will not stop for numerous apps the requirement to recover a document because of a shut down.

Comment: I can’t be certain but I suspect the author wants to disable Windows 10+ to restore an applications status upon a restart. Since that feature is a Windows feature, which doesn’t exist in Windows 7, there likely is a more detailed answer to this question that exists

Comment: I did not interpret the question this way, but you make a good point and I added a follow up on restarting Apps on sign in.  This will not prevent all document recover processes.

Comment: I added clarification.